# What happened to `hiding` when importing/exporting module functions/types in Elm?

Tags: elm

I've kept an eye on Elm development for the past couple years and finally got the chance where I could do a POC using Elm! I seem to remember that `hiding` was a way to import every function/type in a module that was exposed *except* what was listed in the `hiding ()` list.

Was that feature removed? I've tried to search for an answer, but haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of Elm ever having the `hiding` keyword. Although this is a feature that is available in Haskell.

If it did exist in an earlier version of Elm then it was removed at least 5yrs ago.